# A very simple geometric/visual example of what a simplex looks like

Tags: linear-algebra, simplex

I was trying to understand what a simplex was intuitively by constructing an example.

Consider only points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. From wikipedia the definition seems to be:

Choose k+1 points $u_0, ..., u_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. are affinely independent (i.e. $u_1 - u_0, ..., u_k - u_0 $ are linearly independent).

So I choose $u_0 = <1,2>$ and $u_1 = <1, -2>$ and the "simplex" they seem to span seems to me more of a parallelogram than a triangle. Which I found confusing. I will admit I don't know a rigorous topological definition of a triangle, however, intuitively it doesn't look like a triangle.

It looks like this to me:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplex formed by two vectors is a line segment.  The problem with your picture is that you shaded the region where $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ are between $0$ and $1$, but without the condition that their sum is $1$.  Your picture should be the segment between the endpoints of the vectors.

Comment: ah!!!!! ur right! no wonder! Thanks so much Michael! They don't let me accept ur answer yet lol!

Comment: but in a more general space, how would I check if it looks like a (generalized) triangle? Do you know the definition to check this?

Comment: @Pinocchio The real definition of a simplex is not appropriate for your situation.  I can give you an idea in three dimensions, however.  Consider the three coordinate axes $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$.  The simplex defined by those you can picture by constructing the triangle between the points.  Alternately, take the pyramid formed by those points and the origin, it will have three faces on coordinate planes while the fourth face is the simplex.  Take three of your fingers, align them along the axes and look at the triangle formed by the tips of your fingers.

Comment: What do you mean the real definition of a simplex? Is the wikipedia definition I mention in my original question not correct? I genuinely wouldn't know.

Comment: I was thinking about a topological simplex.  The definition of a simplex in a vector space as you describe is the right definition for this setting.